# Which context should I pass to a superclass?

Tags: java, android, inheritance

Big problem with passing **context** to my class. I tried almost everything : getApplicationContext() / getBaseContext() / getContext() **->** is not available with the autocompletion / this. **At this moment**, `this` almost work (*I mean it is not null*).

```
public class PersonActivity extends Activity implements OnTaskCompletedInterface {

    public PersonAdapter listAdapter ;

    public PersonActivity() {
        try {
            PersonGetAsync asyncGet = new PersonGetAsync(this, this, this);
            asyncGet.execute().get; // supposed to block the UI I know
        // With this, I catch the exception
        }catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
public PersonAdapter getListAdapter() {
        return listAdapter;
    }
```

For details, here is the child :

```
public class PersonBlueActivity extends PersonActivity {

private ListView lv_Person;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_person_chooser_blue);

    lv_Person = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_person_chooser_blue_lv);
    lv_Person.setAdapter(getListAdapter());
    lv_Person.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    lv_Person.setClickable(true);
}
@Override
    public PersonAdapter getListAdapter() {
        return super.getListAdapter();
    }
```

and here is the Async

```
public class PersonGetAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Activity mActivity;
    Context mContext;
    String response;
    private OnTaskCompletedInterface listener;

    public PersonGetAsync(Activity activity, Context context, OnTaskCompletedInterface listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        mActivity = activity;
        mContext = context;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        String str = "Connexion en cours";
        dialog.setTitle(str + "...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
        response = "";
        try {
            //Appel du webservice
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(Globale.webURL+Globale.PERSON);

            // Envoi de la requête GET
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

            Log.v("Get : ", response);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listener.onTaskCompleted(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

But, because my context doesn't pass, I can't go over this step : [image: DebugLog]

It raise me a "**NullPointerException**" why ?

Comment: You shouldn't be initializing this in the Activity constructor. You're probably getting a NPE because the Activity hasn't been built yet.  Do this in onCreate() and no sooner.

Comment: Thank you DeeV, it worked !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not implement a constructor on an `Activity` subclass.

Do not attempt to use the `Activity` (call methods on it or pass it as a parameter to something else) until inside your `onCreate()` method, and usually not until `super.onCreate()` is called.

The reason why you are crashing is that your `Activity` has not been initialized by the time you are trying to use it with your `PersonGetAsync` class. Delay the creation and usage of `PersonGetAsync` until after the `super.onCreate()` call inside the `onCreate()` method of `PersonBlueActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do this, context should be given as the activity as here you are trying to give the reference to an activity so your asynctask class is not able to recognize that, so you need to give the reference to the activity you are calling asynctask from like as:

```
 ProgressDialog dialog;
    Activity mActivity;
    Context mContext;
    String response;
    private OnTaskCompletedInterface listener;

    public PersonGetAsync(Activity activity, Context context, OnTaskCompletedInterface listener) {
        this.listener = listener;

        mContext = activity;
    }

@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        String str = "Connexion en cours";
        dialog.setTitle(str + "...");
        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Also i see that now, you have not implemented the onCreate() method in your activity.Instead of using making a constructor you can call async in onCreate()

Comment: I don't see how commenting the activity would resolve the problem. I tested, it doesn't work. There is probably a problem with the context, not the activity.

Comment: I passed the activity to mContext, get java.lang.NullPointerException too

Comment: as i mentioned in my answer, remove the constructor and call async task in the onCreate() method

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER EVER use the actual constructor of an Activity.

Override the Activity lifecycle functions and do your work there.

The reason why your context is null when you try to use it with the progress dialog, is because it hasn't been set yet. The context of the activity gets set in the lifecycle functions of the activity, and as the constructor gets called first, this hasn't happened yet.

Move all your constructor code to onCreate and everything will be fine. The onCreate function also gets called once, like the constructor.

Comment: Thank you, it worked ! But CommonsWare was the first to reply, sorry